# Integral Identity Involving Bell Numbers

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

**Is the following identity true ?**

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{b(x)}{B(x)} dx \quad \overset{?}{=} \quad \int_0^\infty \frac{x!}{x^x} dx$$

*where*

$$b(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^x}{n^n} \qquad \text{and} \qquad B(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^x}{n!}$$

**NOTE:** *A short sketch of the demonstration proving the **convergence** of the integral on the **left** can be found **[here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/138896/convergence-and-closed-form-of-an-integral-involving-bell-numbers).** Also, the numerical value of the integral on the **right** is about **2.5179<sup>+</sup>**. Furthermore, if the position of $x$ and $n$ in the numerator of each sum were reversed, and both sums were to start at n = 0, we would have the following identity:*

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{E(x)}{e^x} dx \quad = \quad \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{n!}{n^n}$$

*where* $\lim_{n \to 0} n^n = 1,$ *and*

$$E(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n^n} \qquad \text{and} \qquad e^x = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}$$

Comment: At first glance this seems too good to be true. (But this also applies to the valid formula: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophomore's_dream ) Have you tried to disprove it by (estimating and) calculating both sides by computer? (The left hand side is the tricky part, the right hand side is around: 2.51792 )

Comment: Of course. No luck whatsoever in calculating the left hand side either numerically or symbolically. I don't even know its first digit ! All I know is that it [converges](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/138896/convergence-and-closed-form-of-an-integral-involving-bell-numbers), and that a man who later deleted his own comments wrote that its numerical value is about 2.5. That's ALL I was able to find out... In almost an entire year ! :-(

Comment: You should also mention your other question about the convergence of the left hand side: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/138896/convergence-and-closed-form-of-an-integral-involving-bell-numbers Alexander Shamov's answer is clearly relevant.

Comment: The value $2.5...$ can be obtained by the mathematica command: NIntegrate[Gamma[x + 1]/x^x, {x, 0, Infinity}]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems that the integral on the left-hand side exceeds $2.57$,
so it's not even close to the numerical value $2.5179\ldots$ of the
integral on the right-hand side.

I told **gp**:

```
b(x) = suminf(n=1,n^x/n^n)
B(x) = suminf(n=1,n^x/n!)
r(x) = b(x)/B(x)
intnum(x=0,25,r(x))
```

and got $2.5793$+.  Since the integrand $r(x)=b(x)/B(x)$ is positive but
apparently decreasing, the Riemann sum $.01 \sum_{n=1}^{2500} r(n/100)$
should be a lower bound on $\int_0^{25} r(x)\,dx$,
and thus on $\int_0^\infty r(x)\,dx$; and already that lower bound
exceeds $2.57$: replacing the last **gp** command above by

```
sum(n=1,2500,.01*r(.01*n))
```

returns $2.5755599998001798\ldots > 2.57$.

Comment: What is ‘GP’ ? Mathematica, for instance, can't even handle the integral, numerically, at all, that's why I'm asking. What mathematical software would you recommend ?

Comment: My version (5.2) has significant problems calculating even as much as a single value of the function in question, let alone 2500 of them... Not sure why, but that's it.

Comment: @Lucian: Sorry, I think I spoke too soon; seems indeed not easy for mathematica to crunch this out of the box---perhaps a more clever reformulation is needed!

Comment: What version of Mathematica are you using ? Because I thought of installing a newer one, but I'm afraid they might not be any better either. At least the old one is small, and I'm generally pleased with it, a few small bugs notwithstanding.

Comment: @Lucian: I'm using v8.0; also, I think we should move our "how to do this on mathematica" question to http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/ --- I downloaded and tried pari/gp, and it works like a charm! (sorry Noam, for the comment noise!)